# How to enter data into specific user

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am new with firabase and vuejs. I got problem how to add *symptoms* in user collection based on the ID.
[Firebase- User collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8sdi.png)

this the UI where the user selected the symptoms, as example: i login the system , and i selected the symptoms, *selected* data add into my user collection in the Firebase

```
<v-card v-if="!toggleSymptom">
  <v-container @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
    <p>{{ selected }}</p>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Diarrheal"
      value="Diarrheal"
    >
    </v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Vomit"
      value="Vomit"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Red Eyes"
      value="Red Eyes"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Tiredness"
      value="Tiredness"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Dehydrated"
      value="Dehydrated"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Greasy Stools"
      value="Greasy Stools"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Swollen Lymph nodes"
      value="Swollen Lymph nodes"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="handleSubmit"> Submit </v-btn>
  </v-container>
</v-card>
```

This is the *script*

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { addDoc, collection, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {

};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default {
components: {},

data() {
 return {
  selected: [],

};
},

methods: {

async handleSubmit() {
    if (this.selected.length != undefined) {
    const docRef = await db
      .collection("symptoms")
      .doc("users")
      .set(this.selected);
    console.log(docRef);
  },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a specific user document you have to retrieve the user document ID and then [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) the symptoms field value.

```js
const docRef = await db
   .collection("users")
   .doc("<USER_DOCUMENT_ID>")
   .update(this.selected);
```

If you want to add an item to an array you should use [arrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)